# How to defer query execution in NHibernate QueryOver

Tags: c#-4.0, queryover

I am trying to execute 3 queries but want to execuate all at one database call. I gone through https://ayende.com/blog/3979/nhibernate-futures but it still executes each query individually. I am using QueryOver instead of CreateCriteria.

Can anyone help how to achieve this?

my query is like

```
            var changedScriptsInHeader = _session.QueryOver<ProgramHeader>()
                                    .Where(x => x.ModifiedTime.IsBetween(changedFrom).And(changedTo))
                                    .Select(x => x.ScriptNumber)
                                    .Future<string>();

            var changedScriptsInDetail = _session.QueryOver<ProgramDetail>()
                                    .Where(x => x.UpdatedDate.IsBetween(changedFrom).And(changedTo))
                                    .SelectList(list => list.SelectGroup(pr => pr.ScriptNumber))
                                    .Future<string>();

            var changedScriptsInReplay = _session.QueryOver<ProgramReplay>()
                                    .Where(x => x.UpdatedDate.IsBetween(changedFrom).And(changedTo))
                                    .SelectList(list => list.SelectGroup(pr => pr.ScriptNumber))
                                    .Future<string>();
```

Thanks